# Angular dialog window doesn't appear for some reason

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to implement a dialog window for my project but I can't get it to work for some reason. The dialog window doesn't open, but the dialog component's content is added at the end of the page like an HTML element without dimming the rest of the page instead. It's not like I'm doing anything complex. I'm just trying to open a simple dialog window for now. I'm not really writing anything different than the people on Youtube, or the official documents. I checked the code multiple times but couldn't locate the mistake. Am I missing something?

Dialog component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-dialog',
     templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor() { }


     ngOnInit() {
     }

}
```

Dialog HTML:

```
<p>
     dialog works!
</p>
```

Main page component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogComponent } from './Components/dialog/dialog.component';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

     constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
          this.openDialog();
     }

     openDialog() {
          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
               width: '500px',
               height: '1080px'
          });

          dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
               console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
          });
     }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DialogComponent } from './Components/dialog/dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
     declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          DialogComponent,
     ],
     imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          AppRoutingModule,
          FormsModule,
          MatDialogModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule,
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent],
     entryComponents: [
          DialogComponent
     ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please make sure you have ALL the bare minimals in place. otherwise it would not work:)** http://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

you are missing the MatDialogRef in your constructor of your dialog

```
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {
}
```

main page component

calling like this is not possible (the UI is not ready then):

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
      this.openDialog();
 }
```

it should be (or afterviewinit)

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ...

    ngOnInit() {
       this.openDialog();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this the full code? If so just adding this isn't working either.

Comment: I need to check what is mandatory to be be passed.  I just added the items that I saw on the top of my head.  Do you need any data to be passed, then you need more.  Please check these steps.  https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview.  it shows you all you need

Comment: Nope. I just want to open a simple dialog window. Nothing fancy for now.

Comment: It still isn't working. Running openDialog() inside lifecylce hooks give an entirely different error so I tried running it via a button. Still the same result. I'm losing my mind lol. Is it possible that I am misinformed about dialogs? Maybe it is working as intended but I'm just not aware of it. A dialog is a window that appears in the centre of the screen while dimming the rest of the page... right?

Comment: yep should be.  It works, i'm sure.   sometimes it's good to leave something for an hour and look at it again :)  what error you get?

Comment: You're right, it should work. I see no error no matter how much I look at it. I copied code from the official documents, Youtube videos, and your reply as well but still no luck. I've got no idea why this is happening. :/

Comment: just out of curiosity, can you remove the selector and the styleUrls from the dialog component definition for now (in the dialog)

Comment: Nothing changes. "dialog works!" still pops at the end of the page with default dialog animation. T_T

Comment: Umm, what do you mean? I'm kinda new to this stuff. I downloaded material via npm and included the modules. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Please make sure you have ALL the bare minimals in place. otherwise it would not work:)  https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Oh it was the stylesheet all along. Thank you very much :)

Comment: your welcome. yes in the end yes, but you were missing the rest too.  you will not forget this easily next time :)